# How to use the __init__ from the main object class in an inherited class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

I have a program that I will be using inheritance in:

```
class Templates(object):

    def __init__(self, esd_user, start_date,
                 summary, ticket_number, email_type):
        self.esd = esd_user
        self.strt_day = start_date
        self.sum = summary
        self.ticket = ticket_number
        self.email = email_type

    def gather_intel(self):
        if self.email == "pend":
            PendingEmail(self.esd, self.ticket,
                         self.strt_day)
        elif self.email == "generic":
            GenericEmail(self.esd, self.ticket,
                         self.strt_day)
        elif self.email == "resolve":
            ResolveEmail(self.esd, self.ticket,
                         self.strt_day)
        elif self.email == "osha":
            OshaEmail(self.esd, self.ticket,
                      self.strt_day)
        else:
            return False


class PendingEmail(Templates):
    pass


class GenericEmail(Templates):
    pass


class ResolveEmail(Templates):
    pass


class OshaEmail(Templates):
    pass
```

Is it possible for me to use the `__init__` from the `Templates` class as the `__init__` for the other inherited classes, without having to rewrite the `__init__` method? Would a call to `super` be necessary here?

For example, is this the proper way to inherit the `__init__` function from the main `Templates` class?

```
class PendingEmail(Templates):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Templates, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to add anything to the `__init__` for the subclasses, just don't implement it, and they'll inherit it automatically. Otherwise, you're a little off for cases where you need to do further initialization:

```
class PendingEmail(Templates):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PendingEmail, self).__init__()  # Name your own class, not the super class
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense, I was reading about it and for some reason I just wasn't getting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like any other method, classes automatically inherit `__init__` from their superclasses. What you want to achieve is already happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define an `__init__` method in your subclass, your base class `__init__` will still get called. If you define one, then you need to explicitly call it like you have described before/after any other actions you need. The first argument to super is the class where it is being called.